# Visual Studio 2012 fails to open Visual Studio 2010 projects

Tags: visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I tried to open in Visual Studio 2012 a VS 2010 solution and I get these error:

Unable to read the project file "Language.vcxproj".
D:...\Language\Language.vcxproj(2,33): The tools version "4.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "2.0".

It has something to do with the ToolsVersion attribute:

[image: ToolsVersion]

I believe this may be something with target platform settings, or with the version of the .NET framework, or with the version of the C++ compiler.

BTW, this also happens with .csproj files contained on other solutions I have.

What annoys me more is that I have a colleague that can open those solutions in his computer without any problem and I can not.

In the Control Panel, I have this items for the .NET framework:

- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 SDK

Help, please!

Comment: Your VS2012 install is broken.  This tends to happen when you had it installed earlier, maybe a beta or trial version, and it wasn't uninstalled properly.  Which leaves junk behind in the registry, reinstalling VS2012 will skip feature installs when your registry says that the feature is already present.

Try to recover by rerunning setup.exe from the command line with the /uninstall /force options.  Hopefully that fixes your registry so a reinstall puts the missing features back.

Comment: @HansPassant: No. It is a fresh install. I just installed it now.